# Upload profile image with AF-Networking using formData

Tags: objective-c

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"multipart/form-data"];

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"RequestCode\":\"%@\",\"RequestType\":\"%@\",\"DocumentTypeCode\":\"ABC123\"}", reqCode, type];
NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"request" : jsonString};
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseUrl,uploadFile];
```

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op =   [manager POST:URLString parameters:parameter constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id formData) {

```
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]
                               name:@"Files"
                              error:nil];

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Success %@", operation.responseString);
    // [self  parseData:responseObject withHandler:completionHandler];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error %@ \n  Response %@", error, operation.responseString);
    completionHandler(NO);
}];
[op start];
```

I tried with this Code but rising error like -

Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7c0a4980 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://prithiviraj.vmokshagroup.com:8033/api/upload, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://prithiviraj.vmokshagroup.com:8033/api/upload, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x7c04d880 "The request timed out."}

Response (null)

please anyone help me to resolve this.
Thanks and Regards
Manasa

Comment: Are you sure that your server is ok?

Comment: Yes,It's Working in postman